# What is meant by correlation structure?

Tags: definitions, correlation

I know only about the Pearson's correlation coefficient in literature.

[Covariance](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/covariance) between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is defined as

$$Cov[X, Y] = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])]$$

[(Linear) Correlation](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/linear-correlation) between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is defined as

$$Corr[X, Y] = \dfrac{Cov[X, Y]}{\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)}$$

Covariance is a measure of association between two random variables whereas correlation measures how much dependent they both are on each other.

Consider the following excerpt mentioning "correlation structure" from `section 2: General Design Principles` of the research paper titled [Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Szegedy_Rethinking_the_Inception_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf)

> Theoretically, information content cannot be assessed merely by the
> dimensionality of the representation as it discards important factors
> like correlation structure; the dimensionality merely provides a rough
> estimate of information content.

What is meant by the "correlation structure" mentioned here? Is it a graph on input random variables? Is it in any way related to the aforementioned correlation?